# How to add name and ID attributes to custom BLE characteristics C++

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, mbed

I am using [this](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/code/BLE_GATT_Example/) mbed workthrough, to create a custom GATT Service in C++. However, this code only creates characteristics with UUIDs:

```
uint16_t customServiceUUID  = 0xA000;
uint16_t readCharUUID       = 0xA001;
uint16_t writeCharUUID      = 0xA002
```

In my C# code on the smartphone connecting to my mbed based device however, I am trying to access the `Characteristic.ID` and `Characteristic.Name` attributes, which the standard characteristics in the standard profiles have, but mine do not. How to I add this information to the characteristics?

In my C# code, I have the following:

```
try {
    foreach(var data in services)
    {
    if (data!=null && data.ID == 0xA001.UuidFromPartial()){ GasSenseService = data; }

    Debug.WriteLineIf (data!=null, "data not null");
                Debug.WriteLine ("Name:", data.Name);
                Debug.WriteLine ("ID:", data.ID);

    }
}
catch {
...
```

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what you want to achieve and an which platform you are currently working on (mobile phone and board )?

Comment: @pan- I am using the nrf51-DK with mbed and C# with Xamarin for cross platform mobile development.  Please see the question edit for more details on what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic name is a descriptor.

You need to add the correct descriptor used by the API to find `Characteristc.Name`.

[This page](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/), links to a document with [standard descriptors](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf).

I bet if you create a descriptor with ID `0x2901` (attached to your characteristic) and set its value to "My Chracteristic", then `Characteristc.Name` will be "My Chracteristic" in your C# code.

Comment: OK, thanks for this. I am trying to work out how to integrate this into the mbed API. Do you have any experience with this? Not to worry if not, I will mark this as the answer once I have worked it out and tried it!

Comment: Never worked with this API, but I already worked with the NRF API on PC, and I remember I had to read this specific descriptor to get the name of characteristics for devices I was connected to.

Comment: OK, not to worry, I'll keep looking at it :)

Comment: I have found [this](https://github.com/ARMmbed/ble-nrf51822/issues/9) link which seems to show how to set up a descriptor, I'll work on that now

Comment: Good luck with that! ;-)

Comment: Viewing other questions you asked, I suppose you can accept this one ;-)

Comment: Links are dead (403), found this link instead https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf

Comment: I did this with ArduinoBLE but it did not work.